# How do I kill cvlc while watching a stream?

Tags: command-line, ssh, video, vlc, video-streaming

I am watching a stream by using the command
`cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0` on an Ubuntu device with a webcam. How do I exit? I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, `q`, `:q`, etc, and the stream does not quit.

Currently I've just been closing the terminal session and reconnecting. All of the other answers online seem to be how to exit `clvc` after a video file is done playing.

This is on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, running on Linux4Tegra on an Nvidia Jetson.

```
$ cvlc --version
VLC media player 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (revision 3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)
VLC version 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)
Compiled by buildd on bos02-arm64-028.buildd (Apr  9 2020 19:29:44)
Compiler: gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
...
```

Comment: What happens when you press Ctrl+C? That should stop it, normally.

Comment: Ctrl + C seems to work, only after a second or two.

Comment: @terdon Nothing happens, the stream continues to play.

Comment: @Jos Even holding Ctrl + C for several seconds does nothing for me. The terminal window ssh-ing to this device is selected of course. I updated the question with some extra info.

Comment: kill $(pidof cvlc)

Comment: I'm on version 3.0.18. Perhaps that makes a difference. I notice that after pressing Ctrl + C the program spits out an error message `main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 300 ms)` before returning to the prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> will close out of `clvc`.